# How to get the tiles on the tileload event and store it locally ?

Tags: openlayers

I am using openlayers3 to make a small mapping demo , now what i want to do is when the user visits the map demo the first time , ofcourse the tiles are loaded from over the internet , so the 1st time around i would really like to store the map tiles locally , so that when the user visits the map the secound time aronnd the tiles are loaded from the localstorage of the users device rather than from over the internet . So far i have made **[THIS](http://purplefront.net/ol-3-demos/find-geo-location/)** demo .

Below is how i am initilizing the map:

```
var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
        })
    ],
    target: 'map',
    controls: ol.control.defaults({
        attributionOptions: /** @type {olx.control.AttributionOptions} */ ({
            collapsible: false
        })
    }),
    view: view
});
```

Below is how i get notified, everytime a tile is loaded,

```
var source = map.getLayers().item(0).getSource();

source.on('tileloadend', function (evt) {
    console.log('loaded ...');
    console.log(source.getUrls());
    //console.log(tileUrlFunction(evt.tile.getTileCoord(), 1, ol.proj.get('EPSG:3857')));
});
```

If you check the url i have posted , you will see  `console.log('loaded ...');` in the console.  But now what function/method do i use to get the tile , so that i can store it locally ? I.E. store the tile locally ?

Answer (score 1):

If you use an XML file to reference your OSM map, you can create a `Cache` setting to make it so that map tiles are cached locally.

Here is an example of one of mine:

```
<GDAL_WMS>
  <Service name="TMS">
  <ServerUrl>http://tile.openstreetmap.org/${z}/${x}/${y}.png</ServerUrl>
  </Service>
  <DataWindow>
    <UpperLeftX>-20037508.3427892</UpperLeftX>
    <UpperLeftY>20037508.3427892</UpperLeftY>
    <LowerRightX>20037508.3427892</LowerRightX>
    <LowerRightY>-20037508.3427892</LowerRightY>
    <TileLevel>17</TileLevel>
    <TileCountX>1</TileCountX>
    <TileCountY>1</TileCountY>
    <YOrigin>top</YOrigin>
  </DataWindow>
  <Projection>EPSG:3857</Projection>
  <BlockSizeX>256</BlockSizeX>
  <BlockSizeY>256</BlockSizeY>
  <BandsCount>3</BandsCount>
  <Cache />
</GDAL_WMS>
```

More info can be found [here](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_wms.html). Scroll down until you get to the `Cache` portion. You'll see there's some customization you can do.